# should use changeNotiferProxyProvider on all providers

Tags: flutter, state, changenotifier

I have a question

I am building app in flutter for first time and totally new to this language

So usualy we create APIs to get all config data n everything which is needed in app so that I can change anything in app remotely without pushing builds frequently

So I need this config in all other providers as I am doing api calls within providers it self n then notify the UI as data changes

But for this to work I have to create all providers as changeNotiferProxyProvider and pass the config provider ref in create method, so that I can access the config provider via the ref I just passed while creating new provider

Do you guys think this is good approach?

Or m gonna mess up in future?

Please help..

Thanks